# TableView Height can not resize in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to do something like this, i have a `UIViewControler`. So in my story board i drag and drop a `UITableView` to the view. I'm supposed to show few customized rows in that table view. but i want to dynamically change the height of that table view.(According to the row count inside the table view).

i tried like below code, but nothing worked so far.

```
CGRect tvframe = [tableView frame];
 [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tvframe.origin.x, 
                            tvframe.origin.y, 
                            tvframe.size.width, 
                            tvframe.size.height + 20)];
```

and also i have tried this

```
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size = self.tableView.contentSize;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

but nothing worked for me.. please some one tell me how do i do this.

thank you.

Comment: at what event you are setting the table's frame?

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: @SanjayMohnani i using this in viewDidLoad event

Comment: @AshishKakkad yes i am using auto layout

Comment: @Darshana, please ensure that you are setting the table's frame after reload event

Comment: If it's autolayout then you can not set frames. you have to use constraints @Darshana

Comment: @AshishKakkad would you explain it bit further ashish ? you mean adding constrains for the views using "Add missing constraints" ?

Comment: @SanjayMohnani i used this code even in the viewWillApear after [table reloadData].. but nothing happens

Comment: I have added as answer. You have to outlet the constraits and you have to change the constant values of it. In the autolayout you have to do it. @Darshana

Comment: @Darshana try setting frame inside viewdidappear

Comment: @SanjayMohnani that worked. but since i have used a scroll view when i scroll the view (not the table view) it disappear again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Autolayout if you want to change the frame then try the constraints (`IBOutlet` of `NSLayoutConstraint`).

[image]

Set the constraint outlets and change `constant` value by :

```
self.sampleConstraint.constant = 20
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Ok, You have to add one constraint for height. and change when the data will filled in table. @Darshana

Comment: @Darshana Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer may helps you...

For Dynamic TableviewCell Height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *OptName_length = @" Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam";
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]};
CGRect rect = [OptName_length boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width-150.0, MAXFLOAT)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:attributes
                                              context:nil];

CGSize requiredSize = rect.size;
return requiredSize.height +5.0f;
}
```

The value 150.0 is Static width of label or textview in cell. OR apprx width or horizontal space value of other elements in leading  or  trailing to the label. Set leading , trailing, top and bottom constraints to the textview in cell don't set static height

Adjust the tableview height to the no. of cell...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
[self adjustHeightOfTableview];
}

- (void)adjustHeightOfTableview
{
CGFloat height = tblMainMenu.contentSize.height;
CGFloat maxHeight = tblMainMenu.superview.frame.size.height - tblMainMenu.frame.origin.y;

// if the height of the content is greater than the maxHeight of
// total space on the screen, limit the height to the size of the
// superview.

if (height > maxHeight)
    height = maxHeight;

// now set the height constraint accordingly
self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}];
}
```

[image: Tableview auto layout constraint image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = resourceArray.count*row_height;
self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
CGFloat height = self.tableView.rowHeight;
height *= [myArray count];

CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
tableViewFrame.size.height = height;
self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 100.0; // expected height
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it helps..

if your row count is fixed than u can do these without constraints dynamically..

in your projects .h file..

```
UITableView *tbl;
int numOfRows;
float tableViewheight,tableViewWidth,heightForRow;
```

in your projects .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 heightForRow=70;
 numOfRows=2;
 tableViewheight=heightForRow*numOfRows;
 tableViewWidth=self.view.frame.size.width;

 tbl=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, tableViewWidth, tableViewheight)];
 [tbl setDelegate:self];
 [tbl setDataSource:self];
 [self.view addSubview:tbl];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return heightForRow;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return numOfRows;
}
```