# Autolayout Parent view height change

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have parent view at top of screen let say TOPVIEW in storyboard which contains some fixed height subview

and scrollview following TOPVIEW

Looks Like

```
UIVIEW

  - TOPVIEW (128) FIXED
  - SCROLLVIEW
```

When keyboard appears i want to set top view to 0 that's why i have taken `IBOUTLET` for same and set to 0 and top view clips bounds to YES

But constraint breaks of subviews of topview (Vertical space between views etc)

My question is how to solve constraints break due to parent view height in subview ,

i know one that we can set priority low for breaking constraint but is there any other way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put the top view and the scroll view in a vertical `UIStackView`. When you want to hide the top view, set `topView.hidden = true`. The stack view will automatically move the top of the scroll view up so it fills the space where the top view was.

Comment: thanks for answer , application have ios 8 support too and stackview is ios9 supported only

Comment: Check out [`TZStackView`](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView).

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you have set fixed height constraint to the TOPVIEW and you are changing that constraint constant value dynamically, so auto layout would have to break the constraint.

If you have set ideal constraints to the TOPView and ScrollView then you would just need to make two or three changes in your constraints as below,

**Step 1:**

Change the height constraint (128) relation from **Equal** to **Less than or Equal** as show in the image below,

[image]

**Step 2:**

If you have set the scrollView constraint correctly as explained in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624873/ios-scrollview-needs-constraint-for-y-position-or-height/35625897#35625897), then you just have to make one change that is change the **BottomSpace Constraint** Relation from **Equal** to **Greater than or Equal** of the component which is at the bottom of scrollView (inside scrollView).

**Step 3:**

Create an outlet of Height constraint of TopView and toggle its constant value from 128 to 0 and vice versa.

That's it, it should work now as expected.

Hope it helps you.

**Update**

Alternatively you can also go for other way as explained below,

**Step 1:**

Change the bottomSpace constraint priority of component inside TOPView at the bottom of TOPView to 999.

**Step 2:**

Select the Clips Subviews property from attribute inspector as show in the image below,

[image]

To prove this, i have done small demonstration app and you can see the result below,

[image]

Orange View has TopSpace to SuperView, Leading and TrailingSpace to SuperView and Height constraint.

Blue View has TopSpace, Leading, TrailingSpace and BottomSpace to SuperView i.e OrangeView, BottomSpace constraint has priority of 999. And it has Height constraint.

This will do the trick.

Comment: i am doing same , height constant to 128 and 0 Vice versa , there is no problem , problem is constraint of subviews of TOPVIEW break because of height of TOPVIEW  = 0

Comment: Apply the same thing to the subViews inside TOPView also that is if any view has fixed height then just change its relation from Equal to Less that Equal. And you can also set an identifier to the constraint to identify it in the constraint break log.

Comment: what about vertical space !! need to do same less than or equl to  ?