# Bottom Constraint with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Im trying to make a dynamic UIScrollView, using this answer I could make it work [Calculating contentSize for UIScrollView when using Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948904/calculating-contentsize-for-uiscrollview-when-using-auto-layout/38969007#38969007)

These are my label constraints: [image]

The scroll is working, but since I have the bottom constraint the view will always have the huge space in the bottom. But if I remove the bottom constraint the scroll will not work. How can I keep the constraint but at the same time don't have all this huge space? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to make the view inside the scroll view to have the same height as the label so i don't have that huge bottom constrain, doing that solved my problem since the new bottom constrain is now 8 instead of 595.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same size and location of the picture, I suggest to 
delete the "595" Bottom Space constraint and instead set a height constraint on the UILabel. This will get rid of all that huge space.

Comment: Ok i got the height using this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34430402/6027418) but now the scrollview doesn't work again because of the lack of the bottom space constrain.

Comment: What are your constraints on your scroll view?

Comment: Solved my problem, maybe its no the best way but it solved anyway. Thanks for the help, Mochi.