# scrollview has ambiguous scrollable content height & Width

Tags: ios, swift, height, width, scrollview

How Can i solve it. I try all type of constraints like top, bottom, left , right, horizontally, vertically, also equal height and width plz see the link below for image

[image]

Comment: @zemoon how you show image through url

Comment: You should be able to do so after 10 reputation.

Comment: Please show Storyboard ViewController image. So People can give you more precise solution. Also one more thing, you have added Page Control Inside Scroll View, but there are also need to add content View and then add page control.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948904/calculating-contentsize-for-uiscrollview-when-using-auto-layout/38969007

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Scroll views are special when you set constraints. Because they have an undefined content size you must set constraints for both its contents' sizes *and* edges. Setting only top, bottom, left, right is not enough, also set height and width.

**Try this.** Add a single `UIView` to an otherwise empty scroll view. Then tie the edges of the view to the scroll view. Finally set the height and width to fixed size.

[Read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html)

Comment: I have done this but its showing me again same error

Comment: Are you sure you tied all edges and set the height and width? Did you also have _only_ one view inside your scroll view? Was the error from this scroll view, as you seem to have several scroll views in your design.

Comment: This worked for me, and in fact is the solution implemented by Xcode when you ask it to add constraints to fix the "problem".