# Autolayout with subview screen issue different devices

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have designed simple one page design for universal application. so I had faced issue while checking the 4 inch devices its working fine. other than 5.5 to above devices its not looking good.

```
View(MAINVIEW)
    ScrollView
    View
    Label
     ..
     ..
```

above I have mentioned the structure of the page.below I have mentioned screen shots.
[image]

above Screen shots image I have designed. with all constraints.

[image]

after that I have checked the preview of the page design.
Iphone 4-inch its showing fine. but Iphone 5.5 its showing in bottom not filled whole page view.

Comment: When you add constraints to your scroll view do not add them like Top constraint to TopLayoutGuid and Bottom constraint to BottomLayoutGuide.

Comment: I dont know about  Top constraint to TopLayoutGuid and Bottom constraint to BottomLayoutGuide can you explain clearly.

Comment: When you add constraint to the scroll view just drag from scrollView to the view controllers view and just press Alt key while you add the constraint, this way you will add the constraint with constant value of 0 and not some arbitrary value with layout guide.

Comment: Follow this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624873/ios-scrollview-needs-constraint-for-y-position-or-height/35625897#35625897

Answer (score 0):

It looks like then you have set the height constraint for ScrollView or view. If you did this then remove that height constant and set the bottom constraint which should have 0 constant value to its superview.

Comment: can you explain where I need to set the constant value.

Comment: If you double click on that constraint you will see options for constant